# No operating system found on USB

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb

I used to run Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

I decided to switch to Ubuntu 14.10.

I booted it up on my USB and loaded it.

It started in demo mode.

I started the install process and I could do all but the last step. Partioning might be one of the steps and I might probably have done it. The last step was to name the device and such.

I saw that my keyboard was non-functional.

I shut-down my computer.

Now, if I try to boot my HDD, it just shows a screen with a blinking `_` and if I try to boot my USB stick it says, `An operating system wasn't found. Try disconnecting ... blah...(no technical info)...blah.. press Ctrl+Alt+Delete to restart
_`

The laptop is some Lenovo IdeaPad S10-3C. The BIOS is some crappy American Megatrends with no customization almost.

Comment: How is your first sentence relevant?

Comment: I gave you all I had. It used to work normally back then, so just mentioned it.